# IE11のwebsocketにおけるbinary送信について

Tags: javascript, websocket, binary

IE11のwebsocketを使用して、以下の3つのファイルを分割して、送信しました。
①全バイト0x00ファイル
②全バイト0x70ファイル
③全バイト0xFFファイル

①～③は全てサイズ100MBファイルです。
FileReaderを使用して、1MBをarrayBufferとして読み込んで、websocketで送信。
この読み込んで送信の流れを100回繰り返して100MB送信します。
結果は以下のようになりました。
②: 10秒
①: 20秒
③: 40秒
何度試しても、同様の結果となりました。(誤差はあります)
以下疑問点です。
・なぜ同じファイルサイズであるのに、差がでてくるのか。
・0x70のファイルはなぜ早いのか。

ちなみに、chromeでは、①～③のファイルはすべてほとんど変わらない時間で完了しています。
いろいろとソースを漁ったりしてみましたが、原因がわからないので、どなたかご教授いただければと思います。